# Images Distored and not staying in aspect ratio - I need pure CSS solution

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get all of these different size images to remain undistorted. All the images look great except for the ones that have a smaller width than the container of 285px. I'm ok with the images being blurry because I know we are stretching them. I just want all of them to keep their aspect ratios. The ones that are not working are images #2, #3, and #4.

I can't use any JavaScript for this. It needs to be pure css.

http://jsfiddle.net/pp74fb7b/9/

```
.squaregallerywrap {
width:  285px; 
height: 285px;
}

.squaregallerywrap img {
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
max-height: 286px;
min-width: 286px;
display:block;
margin:auto;
position:relative;
-moz-transform:translateX(-50%);
-webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
-ms-transform:translateX(-50%);
-o-transform:translateX(-50%);
transform:translateX(-50%);
left:50%;
}

li {    
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-transition: 0.4s all linear;
transition: 0.4s all linear;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the images to be square (some will get cropped out) or maintain their aspect ratios leaving some white space?

Comment: Images should be square and it's ok if they are cropped. The background-size:cover will work for me. So consider this question answered. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `background-image` on the div instead? Sizing the image will be much easier that way. I made you [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pp74fb7b/10/) with square images using `background-size: cover;`, which crops them into squares but doesn't distort the images. Here's also [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pp74fb7b/11/), where they maintain their aspect ratios and don't crop using `background-size: contain;`.

Comment: I was thinking that I couldn't use background-image because the images are added dynamically and I wouldn't be able to have the image url in the css file. But the way you have the url inside the div will work! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2mj7ckfn/1/)

If I understand you correctly, you want to maintain images from being undistorted but yet make all of them the same size container, set an explicit `width` and `height` on the `img` tag, and use `object-fit: cover` which acts like `background-size: cover`. Though it isn't supported in IE.

See http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit

Comment: I have never seen object-fit: cover. I learned something new :) Unfortunately it looks terrible in IE. So its really not going to work for me.

Comment: Well I just learnt it recently as well! If supporting IE is the least of your concerns, it's a quick fix rather than converting them to backgrounds.

Comment: I think I can use background-size:cover as long as the image urls are not in the css file. So I'm going to try that.